# Tar only if there is result in find command

Tags: linux, shell, find, tar

I'm using `find` and `tar` in the command:

```
find . -type f -size +10M -name "info*.log" -print0 | tar -zcvf "info.log.tar.gz" --null --files-from - --remove-files
```

How can I change it to only creates `info.log.tar.gz` if there is result in `find`?

Comment: tar generally doesn't create empty tarballs. It tends to error instead in my experience. Is that not happening or are you trying to avoid the error? For the latter, assuming you are sure your arguments will fit into a single command line, you could use `xargs -r`/`xargs --no-run-if-empty`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if clause to first check to see if there are any log files present, this will double your usage of 'find' however.

```
if [[ `find . -type f -size +10M -name "info*.log" -print | wc -l` -gt 0 ]] ; then
  find . -type f -size +10M -name "info*.log" -print0 | tar -zcvf "info.log.tar.gz" --null --files-from - --remove-files
fi
```